# Amount of water and the fine tuning of our ecosystem

Tags: discussion

#### Sandbox.

Is this an OK question?

---

> ```
> Isaiah 40:12
>     Who hath measured the waters in the hollow of his hand, 
>     and meted out heaven with the span, and comprehended 
>     the dust of the earth in a measure, and weighed the 
>     mountains in scales, and the hills in a balance?
> ```

Have read somewhere, can't find where, that if the earths amount of water was only slightly more, "slightly" relative to the amount that exists, life as we know it could not exist. Believe it was 3-4 meters. This because the oceans would absorb too much CO2 and nitrogen.

In light of the fine-tuning of the universe I was wondering if this is a valid point.

This is highly scientific, but interesting in the light of an ordered universe and ecosystem.

---

EOF Q

---

Comment: This seems to be consensus on science questions: http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/3480/3961

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really no.

It's more of a science question, it's not bounded by a theological scope and it's not something that's of significant interest to our expert set (theologians).

You *might* have some luck deciphering the depth and context of the text here on BH which might give you a guide as to whether your thought process is correct, but in general, this is probably too speculative to work on an SE site.

Now, if you found someone who *believed this* and was publishing about it, then you could ask about the specifics of the publication, but as it stands this is too close to *new thought* for it to work here.

Comment: @user129107, you might also want to post your science question (without the Bible verse) on Skeptics; you would get an answer as to whether that part is true or not.

Comment: Thanks, and yes. I see it as well now. When I read over it, it looks more and more miss-placed each time ;P Somehow I did not see it as clear when I posted the Q. @El'endiaStarman: Thanks. I'll might do that if I manage to phrase it in a good / better way.